# how can i iterate a map of hash maps in velocity template expression language?

Tags: java, velocity

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map=new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> mapContents1=new HashMap<String, String>();
mapContents1.put("image_path", "E:/pdfGenerationR&D/logo.jpg");
mapContents1.put("invoice_no", "1234568");
mapContents1.put("invoice_date", "04-08-2016");

HashMap<String, String> mapContents2=new HashMap<String, String>();
mapContents2.put("image_path1", "E:/pdfGenerationR&D/logo.jpg");
mapContents2.put("invoice_no1", "1234568");
mapContents2.put("invoice_date1", "04-08-2016");

map.put("map1", mapContents1);
map.put("map2", mapContents2);
```

above is my java code and below is my html template where i want to set hashmap data into html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Payment Voucher</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <img alt="logo" src="$documentContentHashmap.get('image_path')"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="rightDiv" style="align:right;">
        <label>Invoice Number :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>$documentContentHashmap.get('map1').get($invoice_no)</span><br/>
        <label>Invoice Date :</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>$documentContentHashmap.get('invoice_date')</span>
    </div>
    <table>
    #set ($map = $documentContentHashmap.getMap())
    #foreach ($mapEntry in $map.entrySet())
        <tr><td>$mapEntry.value</td></tr>
    #end
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i get values of map1 statically and map 2 dynamically..

Comment: what do you mean by 'statically' and 'dynamically'?

Comment: table i want to generate dynamically using loop by the key 'map2' and for span tag and image i dont want to loop i just want to set value from key 'map1'.